# What's wrong with this form and MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a PHP form where there are checkboxes for each item.  The checkboxes' names are an unique PHP variable, so as to not have duplicate entries.  When a user checks a checkbox and clicks "Update." The MySQL database should update.  It does not though.  Any suggestion?  Thanks

---

Form:

```
<form action='spam.php' method='post'>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE subject='business' AND active='1' ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0)
  echo "<h3>Article - Business</h3>
<ol>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $active = $row['active'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    $author = $row['author'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $filepath = $row['file'];
    $ext = $row['ext'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    echo "<script>                                      
    <li>$title <input type='checkbox' name='$id' value='0' /><$ext| <a href='$filepath'>Download</a>|<a id='aTag$id' href=''>Details  &darr;</a></li>
    ";

}

if ($numrows == 0)
 echo "";
?>
<br />                                      
<input type='submit' value='Update' name='submitbtn'/>
</form><br />
```

---

Form action:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['$id'])) 

    mysql_query("UPDATE files SET active=0 WHERE id=$id AND subject=$subject");

?>
```

Comment: what is the problem? r u getting some error?

Comment: No, not that I know of.  However, the active field in the database doesn't update...

Comment: Despite the SQL injection? It is *very likely* the SQL is invalid. (Unless `$subject` happens to contain `'`s wrapping it.)

Comment: I'm sorry? Please bear with me, this isn't really my field...

Comment: @user22138 Check the **error status** of the SQL query; there is likely an error with the query caused by it being ill-formed. For instance, imagine if `$subject` evaluates to `foo,bar`. The query will look like: `UPDATE .. AND subject=foo,bar`, which is not valid SQL. This is a form of [accidental] SQL injection.

Comment: Log the SQL statement and run it from console to see what happens or post it here.

Comment: Ah, no, $subject is a single word variable.

Comment: @Axel How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user22138 `UPDATE .. AND subject=foo` is still invalid.

Comment: I suggest you remove all the irrelevant CSS from your question.

Comment: `$query = "UPDATE files SET active=0 WHERE id=$id AND subject=$subject";` then print `$query` prior to executing `mysql_query($query)`.

Comment: @Axel Ahhh... I am getting some undefined variables. Thanks, I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I suggest that You seperate retrieving data from database and echoing input fields.
Secondly, I suppose that

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?=$row['id']?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

looks prettier.

Third thing, You didn't want to try:

```
if (isset($_POST[$id])) ...
```

not

```
if (isset($_POST['$id'])) ...
```

And the last thing, is that we need to know errors or what is wrong.

Comment: There are 3 different errors - syntax errors, which is shown by compiler, runtime which will probably show some errors too by compiler - for example, division by zero will be a runtime error, and logical errors, which are when something is not working as You wanted. So look what kind of error You got.